# 6th and 7th divisor of integer

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

Is there a positive integer $n$ such that $n=d_6 ^ 2 + d_7 ^ 2 -1$, where $d_k$ is $k^{th}$ divisor of $n$? ( $1$ is first, etc., $n$ is last) So far have only concluded that $n$ in that case should have more than $12$ divisors, since $n=d_6 ^ 2 + d_7 ^ 2 -1 > d_6 d_7$ and $d_6$and $d_7$ are not in the middle of array of divisors of $n$. Also, if $d_6$ and $d_7$ are relatively prime, then we would need to solve equation $d_6 d_7 m = d_6 ^ 2 + d_7 ^ 2 -1$, but they are not necessarily relatively prime. Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated. (problem came from one friend)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An identity satisfying the divisors of a positive integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194047/an-identity-satisfying-the-divisors-of-a-positive-integer) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%3Dd_6%5E2%2Bd_7%5E2-1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Adivisor%2C%20OR%20content%3Apositive%20integer&p=1).

Comment: If $\gcd(d_6,d_7)=m>1$ then, since $m\,|\,n$ we'd get $m\,|\,1$, a contradiction.

Comment: "(problem came from one friend)" You can tell this one friend, that he/she can use a search for the stackexchange site.